# valitade zend framework's output

Tags: html, zend-framework, zend-form, validation

I use xhtml1-strict.dtd and validator.w3.org not validate Zend Forms.
Tell me how you can validate Zend's html

use `$view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');`,  but is work only for FormText View Helper  :/

example
Zend output: `<input type="">`
I need: `<input type="" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the doctype from within zf. Get the view helper and modify it, like $this->view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT') in an controller. You should add it to your application.ini if it's a newe version of zf. Check the manual for correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In `application.ini`:

```
resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"
resources.layout[]
```

In your `view/scripts/layout.phtml`

`<?php echo $this->view->doctype(); ?>`

In your `view/scripts/index/form.phtml`

`<?php echo $this->form; ?>`